# How to set out-of-order values to NA?

Tags: r

I am using R to accumulate data that comes every minute from a sensor.
'WIDTH' and 'HEIGHT' should be increasing.
Unfortunately, the data contains NAs and out-of-order values (e.g. row eight has values 12.0, 13.0 which are out of the range).
**What I want is to set out-of-order values to NA.**

Then I'll impute dataset 'ex' by myself.
Since the data may be huge,
I made a procedure like below:

```
m<-15 
for(i in 2:m){
  ex$WIDTH[i]<- ifelse(ex$WIDTH [i]- ex$WIDTH [i-1]<0,NA, ex$WIDTH [i])
  ex$HEIGHT[i]<- ifelse(ex$HEIGHT[i]- ex$HEIGHT [i-1]<0,NA, ex$HEIGHT [i])
}
```

But the result is wrong.

**Origin data set**

```
   ID    CTIME         WIDTH HEIGHT
1  HM001 201212121301 1201.9 1115.5
2  HM001 201212121302 1202.2 1115.8
3  HM001 201212121303 1202.8 1115.8
4  HM001 201212121304     NA 1116.1
5  HM001 201212121305 1203.9 1116.7
6  HM001 201212121306     NA 1116.7
7  HM001 201212121307     NA 1116.7
8  HM001 201212121308   12.0   31.0
9  HM001 201212121309 1206.0 1118.2
10 HM001 201212121310 1206.3 1118.6
11 HM001 201212121311 1206.5 1118.8
12 HM001 201212121312     NA     NA
13 HM001 201212121313 1207.3     NA
14 HM001 201212121314 1207.9 1121.1
15 HM001 201212121315 1208.4 1121.3
```

**result of for statement**

```
   ID    CTIME        ACTIVE_KWH REACTIVE_KWH
1  HM001 201212121301     1201.9       1115.5
2  HM001 201212121302     1202.2       1115.8
3  HM001 201212121303     1202.8       1115.8
4  HM001 201212121304         NA       1116.1
5  HM001 201212121305         NA       1116.7
6  HM001 201212121306         NA       1116.7
7  HM001 201212121307         NA       1116.7
8  HM001 201212121308         NA           NA
9  HM001 201212121309         NA           NA
10 HM001 201212121310         NA           NA
11 HM001 201212121311         NA           NA
12 HM001 201212121312         NA           NA
13 HM001 201212121313         NA           NA
14 HM001 201212121314         NA           NA
15 HM001 201212121315         NA           NA
```

**What I expect (row8 WIDTH=NA, HEIGHT=NA)**

```
   ID    CTIME         WIDTH HEIGHT
1  HM001 201212121301 1201.9 1115.5
2  HM001 201212121302 1202.2 1115.8
3  HM001 201212121303 1202.8 1115.8
4  HM001 201212121304     NA 1116.1
5  HM001 201212121305 1203.9 1116.7
6  HM001 201212121306     NA 1116.7
7  HM001 201212121307     NA 1116.7
8  HM001 201212121308     NA     NA
9  HM001 201212121309 1206.0 1118.2
10 HM001 201212121310 1206.3 1118.6
11 HM001 201212121311 1206.5 1118.8
12 HM001 201212121312     NA     NA
13 HM001 201212121313 1207.3     NA
14 HM001 201212121314 1207.9 1121.1
15 HM001 201212121315 1208.4 1121.3
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update**. My original solution has two defects: it doesn't work if the data contains `NA`s, and it doesn't work for two consecutive out-of-order values. The solution below solves both of these problems; the trick with min is needed as `cummax` doesn't have a `na.rm` argument.

```
SetOutOfOrderValuesToNA <- function(x) {
  min <- min(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  x[is.na(x)] <- min - 1
  x[x < cummax(x)] <- NA
  x
}

> x <- c(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 0.1, NA, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 6, 0.2, 7, 8)
> SetOutOfOrderValuesToNA(x)
 [1] 1.1 2.2 3.3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 6.0  NA 7.0 8.0
```

**Original solution.**

Let's start with a vector first. If

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 0.1, 4, 5, 6, 0.2, 7, 8)
```

then the following code sets *strange* (e.g. out of order) values to `NA`:

```
n <- length(x)
x[-1][x[-n] > x[-1]] <- NA
> x
[1]  1  2  3 NA  4  5  6 NA  7  8
```

It's a good exercise to understand why this works. Next you define a function

```
SetOutOfOrderValuesToNA <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  x[-1][x[-n] > x[-1]] <- NA
  x
}
```

and call it on your data frame:

```
ex$WIDTH <- SetOutOfOrderValuesToNA(ex$WIDTH)
ex$HEIGTH <- SetOutOfOrderValuesToNA(ex$HEIGHT)
```

Comment: would this do value comparisons over the 2 vectors everytime the function is run? I had the impression that @남윤주 was trying to do this as the data is being churned out?

Comment: If what I assumed to be true, then it might just be a matter of doing tail(data, x) and set x to a reasonable number w.r.t. the rate of the data being churned out and running the function over it.

Comment: No problem. Please 'accept' this answer if you believe it does answer your question.

Comment: @VictorK., when I try this function, it doesn't capture the "12" that's out of order in the "WIDTH" column.

Comment: >x <- c(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 0.1, NA, 0.1, 6, 0.2, 7, 8) >x[-1][x[-n] > x[-1]] <- NA >x [1] 1.1 2.2 3.3 NA **NA 0.1** 6.0 NA 7.0 8.0 Would u solve this problem? And can you explain what 'x[-1][x[-n] > x[-1]]' code means? I am begginer of R. Thank you~